# UIViewController - where to put init of instance variables (using Storyboards)

Tags: ios, init

I'm using Storyboards. I need to init instance variables of UIViewController just once. `viewDidLoad` and `awakeFromNib` fire each time I open a viewController from menu (I'm using SWRevealViewController for sidebar menu as in Facebook app). Is it normal for awakeFromNib to fire many times or is it SWRevealViewController bug?

So is there some special init method or do I need to set instance variables from outside of viewController (in AppDelegate?)

**EDIT**:

I found this question
[SWRevealViewControllerSegue, reusing Viewcontrollers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826305/swrevealviewcontrollersegue-reusing-viewcontrollers)
I didn't realize that each time you show a controller via segue it creates a new instance of controller. So what does it mean? Does it mean that if I have a table of data loaded from web API - it will be reloaded each time I go back and forth through segue?.. Doesn't seem very effective to me. Is it normal for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controllers are either recreated or reused depending on the situation. When you push a view controller onto a navigation controller's stack, you almost always push a new instance. When using a tab bar controller, the view controllers it contains are often held in memory. To avoid excessive memory consumption, it makes sense that view controllers are cleaned up when possible, rather than held around.

In the case of your `SWRevealViewController` then yes, it sounds as though your view controller *should* be recreated every time. You ideally shouldn't be directly loading any data from a web API within your view controller; instead, extract your API calls and models into separate classes that you can reuse from *any* view controller. Then, rather than reloading the data over the network when your view controller loads, you just need to fetch the latest data from your model / store class.

Comment: +1 many thanks, I wish I could give +100 for such great answer.